# From a column with diffrents objects, I would like to have many columns for each object, with pandas

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

Using pandas, here is the start point:

```
     months,banana, orange,weight
```

0       january,1000,2000,1000
1       February,500,800,700
2       March,750,1500,1500

And i would like to reach here: instead of 2 columns i would like to have 5 columns without comma.

Comment: you mean the second column is a string with comma? also, we can use some better formatting on the df example. but if I am understanding correctly, you need something like this: `df.iloc[:,1].str.split(',', expand=True)`

Comment: Great! Thank you Da song.